# Saving XML Locations via AppSettings

Tags: c#

I'm an Application Designer Student looking for some guidance.

I want to make an application for my internship which needs to allow a user to add XML files via a textbox which only has to appear the first time you run the application or when it detects a new XML file.

When it is first run it has to have an option to save the location into the appsettings.

Could you guys give me some hints on how to realise this?

This is not homework, my internship asked me if I would be able to make something which will make their work just a bit more easy.

There is no textbook or sorts. If there was I would have consulted that.

Comment: It will be in the TextBook... I think the point is that you *read the TextBook*

Comment: @Greg Sansom I would have if i had an Tektsbook regarding this.

Comment: Wait they want a textbox that is used to add new xml files, buts its only meant to appear if there are new xml files, might just be the wording but isn't that self defeating?

Unless of course you mean the user sticks new XML files in an existing folder and when the app is run if it sees new ones it opens a textbox to allow its location to be added, which sounds redundant as if they have to be put in a certain folder to be watched then they know damn well where the files are and its location 0.o or am i really missing the point here? anyone?

Comment: All the XMLs get added to an map on the server and this will be watched by it,  The exe also get put into this map and will run from there

Comment: @GregSansom Please read the tag-wiki for the homework tag. It should *not* be used. =)

Answer (score 0):

[AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) property is probably what you are looking for. You can add a new entry within the AppSettings using the [GetSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx) method.